# How do I do an Async OkHttp-based REST-call with RoboSpice?

Tags: android, asynchronous, robospice, okhttp

So I looked at the [robospice okhttpclient-sample](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-okhttpclient) at github and was surprised to find that they demonstrate a [synchronous HTTP call](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/release/robospice-sample-okhttpclient/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/okhttp/ReverseStringRequest.java). The second bullet point in the readme of RoboSpice underlines that it "executes network requests asynchronously (in a background AndroidService)". So why a synchronous example? Where's the callback?

I also notice that the OkHttp-library linked into the RoboSpice sample is v1.3, which by now is ancient. The [robospice-okhttp maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.octo.android.robospice%7Crobospice-okhttp-parent%7C1.4.12%7Cpom) library is not much better - linking to v1.5.4 of the library. Both use the synchronous `OkHttpSpiceRequest.open()` function call, which is deprecated in v1.6 and removed in v2.0 (RC). Was the asyncrhonousity first introduced in v1.6?

Have anyone implemented true asynchronous use of OkHttp in RoboSpice and got some example code to go along with it? If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Although Robospice uses OkHttp's blocking API, it uses it from a background thread, not the one you enqueued the request on. So from the application's perspective Robospice is asynchronous.

OkHttp 2.0 will offer both a blocking API and an async API with callbacks. Behind the scenes the callbacks API still uses one thread per call. In future versions of OkHttp we plan to take advantage of SPDY and HTTP/2 by dispatching multiple calls on a single thread.

Comment: How can I replace the SpiceException and RequestListener in Robospice to okhttp